# Node - fluent-ffmpeg RTSP to Kinesis Video Stream PutMedia API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, fluent-ffmpeg

What I'm trying to do is go from RTSP -> FFMPEG -> MKV -> PutMedia in a stream with low latency.

This is the best attempt I have so far which has two problems, the first being authentication doesn't work no matter how which variant of trying to sign the request I use.

```
import KinesisVideo from "aws-sdk/clients/kinesisvideo";
import Stream from "stream";
import aws4 from "aws4";
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import ffmpeg from "fluent-ffmpeg";
import { defaultProvider } from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node";


const client = new KinesisVideo({
    region: "ap-southeast-2",
});
const endpoint = await client
    .getDataEndpoint({
        StreamName: "video-stream",
        APIName: "PUT_MEDIA",
    })
    .promise();
if (!endpoint.DataEndpoint) return { statusCode: 400, body: "No stream found." };
const Writable = new Stream.Writable({
    async write(chunk, _, next) {
        const result = await defaultProvider()().then((creds) => {
            return aws4.sign(
                {
                    protocol: "https",
                    host: endpoint.DataEndpoint?.replace("https://", "") || "",
                    path: "/putMedia",
                    service: "kinesisvideo",
                    method: "POST",
                    region: "ap-southeast-2",
                    headers: {
                        "x-amzn-stream-name": "video-stream",
                        "x-amzn-stream-arn": "ARN HERE",
                        "x-amzn-fragment-timecode-type": "RELATIVE",
                        "x-amzn-producer-start-timestamp": new Date().toJSON(),
                    },
                    body: chunk,
                },
                creds,
            );
        });
        fetch(`${endpoint.DataEndpoint}/putMedia`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: result.headers,
            body: result.body,
        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                return res.text();
            })
            .then((text) => console.log(text))
            .catch((e) => console.log("error: ", e));
        next();
    },
});
ffmpeg("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4").format("matroska").stream(Writable);
```

I have the correct IAM policies `"kinesisvideo:*"` and the current error I'm getting doesn't look IAM related.

The error is:

> the request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the Service documentation for more detials.

At the moment I'm purely trying to get authentication to /putMedia working over fetch.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: So this seems to be something related to how you're authing as opposed to actually how you're putting a stream. What do you mean by `The first task`? Is this 1 question or 2 as the latter would make it eligible for closure.

Comment: Also: can't see where `defaultProvider` is defined here?

Comment: Added the import for defaultProvider and as for the question its worded as two so i'll change that, the question should be "how do i stream rtsp -> kinesis video stream from node"

Comment: The error you currently have has nothing to do with actual streaming hm… I would pose this as an question to first fix your error and then another question if you need help with logic etc.

Comment: I will re-phrase it again, I think if I can solve the authentication i can just fix the streaming logic myself, thanks.

Comment: Okay got it, I’ll edit your question to clarify that - my sim is to help 

Comment: Please console.log the output of creds before you do aws4.sign. what is it? is it actually populated? I’m predicting it’s not.

Comment: "cred's" looks to all be there, obviously can't paste it here but contains a accessKeyId, secretAccessKey and sessionToken - If it goes unsolved for a few more days might create a "AWS-CDK" minimum-viable setup that people can clone